# How can I figure out the physical location of my cloud server?

Tags: linux, physical-environment, geolocation

I'm renting a linux cloud server at a larger server provider somewhere in the US. I do not have physical access to the server - I have no idea where it is. Customer support wasn't able to pinpoint the exact datacenter that the server is located in. Given remote access to the server, what options do I have to figure out its location?

I've tried whois and traceroute, as well as geoip sites, but they yield drastically different results.

Comment: Traceroute is the best way to start, but you'll need significant experience with the network to be able to interpret the results. You may find it better to just post your IPv4 and IPv6 addresses and let someone help you.

Comment: What is this provider and what is the logical location? Also, why is it important for you to know the physical location? Some providers publish approximate location. E.g. [GCP](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/regions-zones) publishes that us-east1 is in Moncks Corner, South Carolina.

Comment: It's Ionos, the server location is shown as USA, but the provider has two datacenters there. Geoip shows the location as Spain however. On one hand it's just interesting, on the other good to know how close to the majority of users the server is.

Comment: @2080 just ask them, how's about that? I do this on regularly base for customer support

Comment: @2080, geoip locations are guesses.  They're often good guesses, but they're still guesses.

Answer (score 2):

The only way to find out where your data is physically located is to ask your cloud provider. The lesson here is simple: any data and apps you have in the cloud are physically stored on a server located at a data centre or server farm. The space is all yours and physically separate so that others cannot access it.